# hyperref for symbols

Tags: hyperref, symbols, cross-referencing, back-referencing, imakeidx

I have the following code, which prints a list of symbols in the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=symbs,title=Index of Symbols,columns=2]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\index[symbs]{abc}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indexes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index of Symbols}
\printindex[symbs]
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

My question is how to make the page (of any symbol) clickable? That said, once I click on the page number, I go directly to that page...

Comment: If I move `hyperref` as the last package to be included, I get clickable page numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (TL 2015), with some improvements. There is no need to use `\addcontentsline` explicitly, since `imakeidx` provides the means for this already. (`hyperref` complains about wrong entries already, best seen on command line!)

As usual (except `cleveref` is in action), `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Why%%%
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[name=symbs,title={Index of Symbols},intoc,columns=2]
\indexsetup{toclevel=section}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\blindtext

\index[symbs]{abc}


\blindtext[20]

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indexes} %%% WHY???


\printindex[symbs]
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```